# Keep getting a syntax error on creating a loop

Tags: python, syntax

```
num = input(float("Enter a number (enter 'q' to quit): ")
p=0
while num>=1:
    p=p+1
```

Why do I keep getting a syntax error on the first p?
Does this mean I can't assign a numerical value on a variable?

Answer (score 1):

You should close the bracket

```
num = input(float("Enter a number (enter 'q' to quit): "))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   import sys
   num = input("Enter a number (enter 'q' to quit)")

   try:
       num = int(num)
    except:
       if num == 'q':
           sys.exit()


    p=0

    while (num>=1):
        p=p+1
        num = num - 1 #otherwise it will go to infinite loop
```